# Reusing storybook components in another project

Tags: reactjs, button, components, storybook

Hi Everyone I have tried to create a component using Storybook and reuse it on another project The method I followed is using an npm package. Although i have successfully published my package when I import it to a new project I am running into errors like
React is not defined.
`ReferenceError: React is not defined
at pa (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:11178:3)

npm i publishstory`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/publishstory
This is my npm package any help  how I can reuse my storybook components I have tried many possible solutions

This is How I have called my component in the new project App.js

**

```
`import React from 'react';
import {Button} from 'publishstory';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
     
    <Button></Button>
    
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;`
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Normally when publishing a library, you're not doing a full minified build of your code. You just transpile it with babel for instance, so it's still readable code.

Your library then needs to define its `peerDependencies` like react, react-dom. You don't ship these dependencies with your library, because the app consuming your library should care for those.

But from what I see you got that last part right already.

You're saying that you get errors that react is not defined in your new app? Well, did you add `react` & `react-dom` as `dependencies` in that said app? Because you really need to have it there and the version should be compatible with what you defined in your library.

If you've done that, I don't see why it wouldn't work. Maybe provide more information on this app?